# How can I reduce this scripting code

Tags: java, rhino

Here is sample code.

```
package base;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Test {

    int value1;
    ScriptEngine engine;

    public Test(){
        this.engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
        this.engine.put("p",this);
    }

    public boolean execute(String script){
        try {
            if (script != ""){
                this.engine.eval(script);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setValue1(int v){
        this.value1 = v;
    }

    public void setValue2(int v){
        this.value2 = v;
    }
}
```

And this is sample script to be execute.

```
p.setValue1(2);
p.setValue2(5);
```

How to reduce script to

```
setValue1(2);
setValue2(5);
```

Edit: I want to run those javascript scripts in method execute() and make script shorter.

Comment: You have to have an instance of your class before you can call non-static methods on it. That's just how OOP works. The test framework is instantiating a Test to a variable "p", and is subsequently calling the `setValue1()` and `setValue2()` methods on it. I don't see how you would be able to reduce the script to anything less.

Comment: @Cory Larson : p.setValue1(2);... is javascript script to be execute. Sorry if I make you misunderstand.

Comment: Yes, I understand. JavaScript still has objects. Your `ScriptEngineManager` creates an instance of `Test` and assigns it to `p` in this line: `this.engine.put("p",this);`. Therefore you must specify the class variable name in your test script.

Comment: @Cory Larson : If an instance must need object to assign. I'll use replace string by searching method (ex. `setValue1();` ) with `p.setValue1();` before execution script.

Answer (score 0):

If "I were you" :P... i will do add a new constructor...

something like:

```
public Test(int value1, int value2){
  super();
  this.value1 = value1;
  this.value2 = value2;
}
```

Comment: I want to run those javascript scripts in method execute() and make script shorter. Sorry if I make you misunderstand